# How to make a .NET API dynamically work with any table in the database without explicitly creating a separate class for each table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

How to make a .NET API dynamically work with any table in the database without explicitly creating a separate class for each table?

I tried to implement this using .NET reflection.

I am currently using:

.NET
Entity Framework
C#
PostgreSQL

and handling GIS data

Currently I am working on a .NET API in which I was initially handling only one table.
I had a Toilets.cs class for representing table schema of a table named toilets and had its `dbcontext` in dbcontext.cs which looked like this:-

Toilets.cs

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace layers
{
    [Table("toilets")]
    public class toilets
    {
        [Key]
        public int gid { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public double tessellate { get; set; }
        public double extrude { get; set; }
        public double visibility { get; set; }

        [Column("ward no")]
        public double wardno { get; set; }
        public string? localityna { get; set; }

        [Column("code no.")]
        public string? codeno { get; set; }

        [Column("geom", TypeName = "geometry (point)")]
        public Geometry? Geom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

dbcontext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure;

namespace layers
{
    public class dbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public dbcontext(DbContextOptions<dbcontext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<toilets> toilets { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<toilets>()
                .Property(x => x.Geom)
                .HasColumnType("geometry");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                var npgsqlOptionsBuilder = new NpgsqlDbContextOptionsBuilder(optionsBuilder);
                npgsqlOptionsBuilder.UseNetTopologySuite(); // Register NetTopologySuite with Npgsql
            }

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I have to make changes to this API such that when a new table is added to the database (even with different number of columns but having geometry), then the API should dynamically map it.

I tried creating a base entity and tried to use this `BaseEntity` as a generic type for `DbSet`.
Also, tried using .NET Reflection for Dynamically adding entity configurations for each table at runtime.

My attempt kind of looks like this

DynamicDBcontext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace layers
{
    public class DynamicDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DynamicDbContext(DbContextOptions<DynamicDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<BaseEntity> Entities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // reflection  (dynamically add entity configurations)
            // for each table in the database at runtime.
            // map each table to the BaseEntity class.
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var entityTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)));

            foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType);
            }
        }

        public async Task<IQueryable<BaseEntity>> GetEntities<T>(string tableName = null) where T : BaseEntity
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
            {
                // Retrieve all data from all tables (excluding the BaseEntity table itself)
                return Entities.Where(e => e.GetType() != typeof(BaseEntity));
            }

            // Retrieve data from the specified table
            var entityType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t =>
                t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)) && t.Name.Equals(tableName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (entityType == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Debugging: Print available types to check if "states" table is recognized
                    Console.WriteLine("Available Types:");
                    foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                    
                }


            }

            // Use reflection to invoke the Set<TEntity> method with the entityType
            var setMethod = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(Set), Type.EmptyTypes).MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
            var dbSet = setMethod.Invoke(this, null);

            // Retrieve all data from the specified table
            return await Task.FromResult(((IQueryable<BaseEntity>)dbSet).AsQueryable());
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                var npgsqlOptionsBuilder = new NpgsqlDbContextOptionsBuilder(optionsBuilder);
                npgsqlOptionsBuilder.UseNetTopologySuite(); 
            }

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

BaseEntity.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [NotMapped] // Exclude this property from the database schema
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

I know it will not work and an Invalid Table Name error is thrown.

Don't know how to implement this.
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't use .NET if I had a requirement to do this in code.  Kind of defeats the purpose of having a statically typed language, there are better languages for dynamic objects (i.e. Javascript).   There are plenty of generators to take an existing database structure and write classes, these are commonly used in database first design.\

Comment: The full power of EF is shown during compilation. But you are doing something at runtime. In this case, EF is not your assistant, just give it up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using stored procedure in PostgreSQL and datatables in Entity Framework.